# `diff -y file-{a,b} | less` and DOS line endings display issues

Tags: diff, less, newlines

In my current job I often have to work with files from Windows machines which most of the time isn't a big deal, but **when piping a side-by-side `diff` to `less`, not only are the `^M` being displayed, but it also messes up the indentation**, like in the following:

```
<U+FEFF>using System;^M                                 <U+FEFF>using System;^M                                 
using System.Reflection;^M                                      using System.Reflection;^M                                      
using System.Runtime.Serializa^M                                        using System.Runtime.Serializa^M                                        
using System.Transactions;^M                                    using System.Transactions;^M
```

(I don't particularly mind the UTF-8 BOM in the first line, as it affects only that one line.)

I know I can do a

> diff -y <(tr -d '\015' < file-a) <(tr -d '\015' < file-b) | less

But that's a heck of a lot to type, and when `file-a` and `file-b` share a long path, you can't use bash's curly braces nicety. And

> diff -y file-{a,b} | tr -d '\015' | less

does not do the trick, as the formatting is already messed up.

Interestingly though, the following displays fine both in terms of `^M` and indentation:

> diff -y file-{a,b} | head

So my question is, how do I get side-by-side diffs piped into less without the aforementioned issues? (Like adding some parameter to diff or less that I'm not aware of)

Comment: What does the display in `diff -y file-{a,b} | tr -d '\015' | less` look like? It lines up for me. By the way, if you want to trim `^M` when they're passed to `less`, you can set the environment variable `LESSOPEN='|-tr -d \\r'`

Comment: @Gilles It looks the same as the diff output posted in my question - except the `^M`s are gone. If that wasn't so, I could use your `LESSOPEN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't to modify files, just print differences, then one option is to simple ignore all white spaces with `-w` option, so that you can use your braces normally

```
diff -wy file-{a,b} | less
```

Of course this method only works if there are no other important changes in whitespace.

If your intention is to repair the files then I would recommend to use `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not fix the issues. It merely changes whether diff considers lines different that differ in whitespace only.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do, but perhaps `dos2unix` converter is what you are looking for.